# How to push to array only reference to variable?

Tags: javascript

My code looks similarly to this:

I create variable:

```
var person1;
```

Than I add this to array:

```
var people = [];
people.push(person1);
```

And finally I define what "person1" is:

```
person1 = new Person("Mike", 25, "London");
```

The problem is, people that are defined after pushing to array are undefined. For some reasons I can't define all people before putting to array. As I see, "people.push(person1);" actually puts copy of this variable to array. It is possible to do, that I put only reference of variable to the array?

Comment: since js is pass by reference for objects/arrays only you need to create person1 as an object first, and then edit its properties

Comment: You cannot create a reference to a variable in JavaScript.

Comment: `var people = {}; people.push(person1);` does not work, it's not an array (`[]`).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an instance of an object and push the object pointer onto the array. Right now the problem is that you are pushing `undefined` since you do not instantiate a `Person` object first.
explicitly your code current looks like this:

```
var person1 = undefined;
var people = [];
people.push(person1);//pushing undefined unto the array
person1 = new Person();//now you have a pointer to an object
```

You have to first instantiate a `Person` then both your variable and array entry will point to the same thing

```
var person1 = new Person(); 
var people = [];
people.push(person1);//pushing a person reference onto the array
person1.someProperty = "lorem" 
people[0].someProperty = "ipsum"
//both person1.someProperty and people[0].someProperty are "ipsum"
```

Similarly you can instantiate the `person` directly in the array and create a variable referencing a object in the array.

```
var people = [new Person()]; //creates an array with a new person object.
people.push(new Person); //adds a new person to the array
var person1 = people[0];
var person2 = people[1];
person1.greet(person2);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no pointers in javascript. `person1` is not going to be a pointer.

This variable is going to reference a value. When the variable is used, the **current** value is referenced. So, when this is used:

```
var person1;
people = [];
people.push(person1);
```

`undefined` shows up because that is what the current value of `person1` was. Any future change to `person1` will change the value of `person1`, but it will not affect any of the values in the `person` array.

It would be more appropriate to take a simpler approach here and just pass in the new value you create

```
people = [];
people.push(new Person("Mike",25,"London"));
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to define `people` as an array `var people = []`

then push to array a default person`new person()`for example, and then refer to person by index `people[1]` (for example), and then change that... to what you want

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is:

```
var person1 = new Person();
var people  = [];
people.push(person1);


people[0].name = "Mike";
people[0].age  = 25;
people[0].city = "London";
```